# i want to collape heading of the table i could'nt able to do it

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
body {
  background-color: #3e94ec;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

div.table-title {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-title h3 {
  color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

th {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  ;
  background: #1b1e24;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-right: none;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color: #666B85;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

tr:hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

td {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

th.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

th.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

th.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

td.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

td.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

td.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Table Style</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesss.css">




</head>


<body>
  <div class="table-title">
  </div>
  <table class="table-fill table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-left">items</th>
        <th class="text-left">calories</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
  </table>



  <table class="table-fill table table-hover">

    <tbody class="table-hover">
      <tr class="header">
        <th colspan="2">
          Bread,cakes and biscuits
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">brown bread and white<br>&emsp;&nbsp; medium size large loaf</td>
        <td class="text-left"><br>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">Cakes-very according to type <br> &emsp;&nbsp; medium slice 2 oz</td>
        <td class="text-left"><br>200-350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">Biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;plain biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;sweet biscuits</td>
        <td class="text-left"><br>60 <br>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="header">
        <th colspan="2">ceriels</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">April</td>
        <td class="text-left">$ 56,000.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left">May</td>
        <td class="text-left">$ 98,000.00</td>
      </tr>



    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: #3e94ec;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

div.table-title {
   display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-title h3 {
   color: #fafafa;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style:normal;
   font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   text-transform:uppercase;
}


/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius:3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

th {
  color:#D5DDE5;;
  background:#1b1e24;
  border-bottom:4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size:23px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding:24px;
  text-align:left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align:middle;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius:3px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius:3px;
  border-right:none;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color:#666B85;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

tr:hover td {
  background:#4E5066;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top:none;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background:#4E5066;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}

td {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:18px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

th.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

th.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

th.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

td.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

td.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

td.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

tr.header
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Table Style</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesss.css">




</head>


<body>
    <div class="table-title">
    </div>
    <table class="table-fill table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">items</th>
                <th class="text-left">calories</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
    </table>



    <table class="table-fill table table-hover">

        <tbody class="table-hover">
            <tr class="header">
                <th colspan="2">
                    Bread,cakes and biscuits
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td class="text-left">brown bread and white<br>&emsp;&nbsp; medium size large loaf</td>
                <td class="text-left"><br>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">Cakes-very according to type <br> &emsp;&nbsp; medium slice 2 oz</td>
                <td class="text-left"><br>200-350</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">Biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;plain biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;sweet biscuits</td>
                <td class="text-left"><br>60 <br>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="header">
                <th colspan="2">ceriels</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">April</td>
                <td class="text-left">$ 56,000.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">May</td>
                <td class="text-left">$ 98,000.00</td>
            </tr>



        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: collapse <thead> after which event? clicking something? hovering on something?

Comment: i want it to be on clicking the <th>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Gif: https://gfycat.com/silentsandyeuropeanpolecat

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xb6gfowL/1/

code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100);
      body {
        background-color: #3e94ec;
        font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
      }
  
      div.table-title {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
      }
  
      .table-title h3 {
        color: #fafafa;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
  
  
      /*** Table Styles **/
  
      .table-fill {
        background: white;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        height: 320px;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        animation: float 5s infinite;
      }
  
      th {
        color: #D5DDE5;
        background: #1b1e24;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
        border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: 100;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: left;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
  
      th:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      }
  
      th:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-right: none;
      }
  
      tr {
        border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
        color: #666B85;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
      }
  
      tr:hover td {
        background: #4E5066;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
      }
  
      tr:first-child {
        border-top: none;
      }
  
      tr:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
  
      tr:nth-child(odd) td {
        background: #EBEBEB;
      }
  
      tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
        background: #4E5066;
      }
  
      tr:last-child td:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      }
  
      tr:last-child td:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      }
  
      td {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
      }
  
      td:last-child {
        border-right: 0px;
      }
  
      th.text-left {
        text-align: left;
      }
  
      th.text-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
  
      th.text-right {
        text-align: right;
      }
  
      td.text-left {
        text-align: left;
      }
  
      td.text-center {
        text-align: center;
      }
  
      td.text-right {
        text-align: right;
      }
  
      tr.header {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-title">
    </div>
    <table class="table-fill table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">items</th>
          <th class="text-left">calories</th>
        </tr>
  
      </thead>
    </table>
  
  
  
    <table class="table-fill table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Bread,cakes and biscuits</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">brown bread and white<br>&emsp;&nbsp; medium size large loaf</td>
          <td class="text-left"><br>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">Cakes-very according to type <br> &emsp;&nbsp; medium slice 2 oz</td>
          <td class="text-left"><br>200-350</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">Biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;plain biscuits <br>&emsp;&nbsp;sweet biscuits</td>
          <td class="text-left"><br>60 <br>80</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
     <table class="table-fill table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th colspan="2">ceriels</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">April</td>
          <td class="text-left">$ 56,000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">May</td>
          <td class="text-left">$ 98,000.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

      

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script>

      $("tr").find("th").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").toggle(); //you can set delay within toggle as well, like .toggle(500);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but when i click on "bread,cakes and biscuits" rows should be collapsed not the entire body .. same as on ceriels its rows should be collapsed can you do this ?

Comment: Yes, see above @shumayil . I updated the code and the demo for you.

Comment: @shumayil Updated the post to add a gif link so it's easy for you to see it has the correct functionality now